# How can I call a file from the same folder that I am in (in script)

Tags: powershell

I would like to call script B from script A without specifying the complete path.
I've tried with

```
.\scriptb.ps1
```

but that doesn't work.
Do I really have to specify the entire path?

(sorry for this quite basic question, but google couldn't help me!)

Comment: Can provide a bit more info: How are you calling script A? Is anything in Script A possibly changing your current location?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

it is possible using `$MyInvocation` as follows:

```
$executingScriptDirectory = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$scriptPath = Join-Path $executingScriptDirectory "scriptb.ps1"
Invoke-Expression ".\$scriptPath"
```

Comment: Thanks. That's how I've done it in the past but I thought there was a better way!

    $workingdir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent  #Get current working directory
. $workingdir\functions.ps1

Comment: since .\scriptb.ps1 is just include its still fully dependent where is it called from. I know it is ugly :)

Comment: Why does Microsoft have to make everything so complicated?

Comment: @ATL_DEV - they *have* come up with a better solution in Powershell 3 and up - `$PSScriptRoot`. PS 3 was released with Server 2012 and Win 8, so 5 years to catch up.

Answer (score 35):

i use the powershell variable which has an easy name to remember what is it for.

```
$PSScriptRoot\scriptb.ps1
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me once I try to reach file in the same folder where the .ps1 script is sitting. Says Unexpected token in $PSScriptRoot\report.xml

Comment: This is the right solution, except it currently doesn't work with shebang scripts: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4217

Comment: Didn't work for me until I did `. $PSScriptRoot\scriptb`

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
& $pwd\scriptb.ps1
```

Comment: So you can do this inside a script?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question.  Posted a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

.\ is relative path. It's relative to where you currently are. For example, if you are in c:\, but calling script d:\1.ps1 then .\ will be drive c:

There're some more tricks to it. You can change your location from  script, using cd for example

.\ will work like you want it to if you will go to location where the file physically is and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your *main* script, script A:

```bsh
$thisScriptDirectoryPath = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$utilityScriptName = "ScriptB.ps1"
$utilityScript = (Join-Path $thisScriptDirectoryPath $utilityScriptName)

$result = . $utilityScript "SomeParameter"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come upon this question, after I found out that executing a Powershell script from a batch file produced failure of "includes" like `.\config.ps1`.

One way to make it work is:

```
$configFullPath = "$($pwd)\config.ps1"
Write-Host "Config file full path = $configFullPath"

#force is required just to make sure that module is not used from cache
Import-Module -Force $configFullPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Payette's book Posh in Action says this works:`${c:File.txt}`

He describes it as:

> “Return the contents of the file File.txt from the current working
>   directory on the C: drive.”

In contrast, `${c:\File.txt}` says,

> “Get the file File.txt from the root of the C: drive.”

Which is fine for Windows. I'm on Linux & trying to find out how to turn the same trick.

So glad to have powershell back in my life.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

What you did:

`.\scriptb.ps1`

What will do:

`. .\scriptb.ps1`